# Post in form not passing to Python

Tags: python, html, forms

First time posting here so excuse me for not being completely clear or not following guidelines well. I have been trying to get this working but so far no luck and I cant figure out why. My "timeinterval" selector in the form passes just fine but the "setpointval" selector will not pass when the form is submitted. I have stripped away the code to bare bones and upon reloading, when i call to obtain the sp in the main(), the form=cgi.fieldstorage does not see the "setpointval" in the form. Any guidance is appreciated.

The code below is capable of creating a chart from the data in the database based on the "timeinterval" selector and I would like to be able to have a setpoint be sent to another python script for control of the system. I have most of the control setup in the other script, its just trying to get the form to maintain the inputted setpoint.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sqlite3
import sys
import cgi
import cgitb

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# global variables
speriod=(15*60)-1
dbname='/var/www/temp_data.db'
setp=0
#sp=get_sp()
#sp = form["setpoint"].value


#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# print the HTTP header
def printHTTPheader():
    print "Content-type: text/html\n\n"
    print 


#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# print the HTML head section
# arguments are the page title and the table for the chart
def printHTMLHead(title, table):
    print "<head>"
    print "    <title>"
    print title
    print "    </title>"

    print_graph_script(table)

    print "</head>"

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# get data from the database
# if an interval is passed, 
# return a list of records from the database
def get_data(interval):

    conn=sqlite3.connect(dbname)
    curs=conn.cursor()

    if interval == None:
        curs.execute("SELECT * FROM temps")
    else:
        curs.execute("SELECT * FROM temps WHERE timestamp>datetime('now','localtime','-%s hours')" % interval)

    rows=curs.fetchall()

    conn.close()

    return rows

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# convert rows from database into a javascript table
def create_table(rows):
    chart_table=""

    for row in rows[:-1]:
        rowstr="['{0}', {1}],\n".format(str(row[0]),str(row[1]))
        chart_table+=rowstr

    row=rows[-1]
    rowstr="['{0}', {1}]\n".format(str(row[0]),str(row[1]))
    chart_table+=rowstr

    return chart_table

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# print the javascript to generate the chart
# pass the table generated from the database info
def print_graph_script(table):

    # google chart snippet
    chart_code="""
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
      function drawChart() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Time', 'Temperature Channel 0'],%s        ]);

        var options = {
          title: 'Temperature'
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
    </script>"""

    print chart_code % (table)



#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# print the div that contains the graph
def show_graph():
    print "<h2>Temperature Chart</h2>"
    print '<div id="chart_div" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>'


#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# connect to the db and show some stats
# argument option is the number of hours
def show_stats(option,sp):

    conn=sqlite3.connect(dbname)
    curs=conn.cursor()

    if option is None:
        option = str(24)

    curs.execute("SELECT timestamp,max(temp0) FROM temps WHERE timestamp>datetime('now','localtime','-%s hour') AND timestamp<=datetime('now','localtime')" % option)
    rowmax0=curs.fetchone()
    rowstrmax0="&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp{0}&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp{1} C".format(str(rowmax0[0]),str(rowmax0[1]))

    curs.execute("SELECT timestamp,min(temp0) FROM temps WHERE timestamp>datetime('now','localtime','-%s hour') AND timestamp<=datetime('now','localtime')" % option)
    rowmin0=curs.fetchone()
    rowstrmin0="&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp{0}&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp{1} C".format(str(rowmin0[0]),str(rowmin0[1]))

    curs.execute("SELECT avg(temp0) FROM temps WHERE timestamp>datetime('now','localtime','-%s hour') AND timestamp<=datetime('now','localtime')" % option)
#    curs.execute("SELECT avg(temp0) FROM temps WHERE timestamp>datetime('2014-03-18 00:00:00','-%s hour') AND timestamp<=datetime('2014-03-18 20:45:00')" % option)
    rowavg0=curs.fetchone()

    curs.execute("SELECT MAX(timestamp),temp0 FROM temps")
    rownow=curs.fetchone()
    rowstrnow="&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp{0}&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp{1} C".format(str(rownow[0]),str(rownow[1]))



    print "<hr>"

    print "<h2>Current Temperatures&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbspCh0</h2>"
    print rowstrnow
    print "<h2>Minimum Temperature &nbsp&nbspCh0</h2>"
    print rowstrmin0
    print "<h2>Maximum Temperature &nbspCh0</h2>"
    print rowstrmax0
    print "<h2>Average Temperatures &nbsp&nbsp&nbspCh0</h2>"
    print "&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp%.3f" % rowavg0+" C"

    print "<hr>"

    print "<h2>In the last hour:</h2>"
    print "<table>"
    print "<tr><td><strong>Date/Time</strong></td><td><strong>Ch0 Temp</strong>&emsp;&emsp;</td></tr>"

    rows=curs.execute("SELECT * FROM temps WHERE timestamp>datetime('now','localtime','-1 hour') AND timestamp<=datetime('now','localtime')")
    for row in rows:
        rowstr="<tr><td>{0}&emsp;&emsp;</td><td>{1} C&emsp;&emsp;</td></tr>".format(str(row[0]),str(row[1]))
        print rowstr
    print "</table>"

    print "<hr>"

    conn.close()



#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
def print_time_selector(option):

    print """<form action="/cgi-bin/webgui1.py" method="POST">
        Show the temperature logs for  
        <select name="timeinterval">"""


    if option is not None:

        if option == "1":
            print "<option value=\"1\" selected=\"selected\">the last hour</option>"
        else:
            print "<option value=\"1\">the last hour</option>"

        if option == "6":
            print "<option value=\"6\" selected=\"selected\">the last 6 hours</option>"
        else:
            print "<option value=\"6\">the last 6 hours</option>"

        if option == "12":
            print "<option value=\"12\" selected=\"selected\">the last 12 hours</option>"
        else:
            print "<option value=\"12\">the last 12 hours</option>"

        if option == "24":
            print "<option value=\"24\" selected=\"selected\">the last 24 hours</option>"
        else:
            print "<option value=\"24\">the last 24 hours</option>"

        if option == "48":
            print "<option value=\"48\" selected=\"selected\">the last two days</option>"
        else:
            print "<option value=\"48\">the last two days</option>"

        if option == "168":
            print "<option value=\"168\" selected=\"selected\">the last week</option>"
        else:
            print "<option value=\"168\">the last week</option>"

        if option == "240":
            print "<option value=\"240\" selected=\"selected\">the last 10 days</option>"
        else:
            print "<option value=\"240\">the last 10 days</option>"

    else:
        print """<option value="1">the last hour</option>
            <option value="6">the last 6 hours</option>
            <option value="12">the last 12 hours</option>
            <option value="24" selected="selected">the last 24 hours</option>
            <option value="48" selected="selected">the last two days</option>
            <option value="168" selected="selected">the last week</option>
            <option value="240" selected="selected">the last 10 days</option>"""

    print """        </select>"""
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
def print_setpoint_selector(sp):

    print """        Setpoint:  
        <select name="setpointval">"""

    if sp is not None:

        if sp == "18":
            print "<option value=\"18\" selected=\"selected\">18</option>"
        else:
            print "<option value=\"18\">18</option>"

        if sp == "19":
            print "<option value=\"19\" selected=\"selected\">19</option>"
        else:
            print "<option value=\"19\">19</option>"

        if sp == "20":
            print "<option value=\"20\" selected=\"selected\">20</option>"
        else:
            print "<option value=\"20\">20</option>"

        if sp == "21":
            print "<option value=\"21\" selected=\"selected\">21</option>"
        else:
            print "<option value=\"21\">21</option>"

        if sp == "22":
            print "<option value=\"22\" selected=\"selected\">22</option>"
        else:
            print "<option value=\"22\">22</option>"

        if sp == "23":
            print "<option value=\"23\" selected=\"selected\">23</option>"
        else:
            print "<option value=\"23\">23</option>"

        if sp == "24":
            print "<option value=\"24\" selected=\"selected\">24</option>"
        else:
            print "<option value=\"24\">24</option>"

    else:
        print """<option value="18">18</option>
<option value="19">19</option>
<option value="20">20</option>
<option value="21">21</option>
<option value="22">22</option>
<option value="23">23</option>
<option value="24">24</option>"""


    print """        </select>
        <input type="submit" value="Display">
</form>"""
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# check that the option is valid
# and not an SQL injection
def validate_input(option_str):
    # check that the option string represents a number
    if option_str.isalnum():
        # check that the option is within a specific range
        if int(option_str) > 0 and int(option_str) <= 240:
            return option_str
        else:
            return None
    else: 
        return None
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# check that the option is valid
# and not an SQL injection
#def validate_input_sp(setpoint_sp):
#    # check that the option string represents a number
#    if setpoint_sp.isalnum():
        # check that the option is within a specific range
#        if int(setpoint_sp) > 0 and int(setpoint_sp) <= 24:
#            return setpoint_sp
#        else:
#            return None
#    else: 
#        return None

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------  
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#return the sp passed to the script
def get_sp():
    form=cgi.FieldStorage()
    if "setpointval" in form:
    sp = form["setpointval"].value
    return validate_input(sp)
#    return sp
    else:
#   print """   Hello World"""
    return None
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#return the option passed to the script
def get_option():
    form=cgi.FieldStorage()
#    print form.keys
    if "timeinterval" in form:
        option = form["timeinterval"].value
        return validate_input(option)
    else:
        return None



#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# main function
# This is where the program starts 
def main():

    cgitb.enable()


    # get options that may have been passed to this script
    option=get_option()

    if option is None:
        option = str(24)
#------------------------------------------------
    # get options that may have been passed to this script
    sp=get_sp()
#    print sp
    setp=sp
#    if sp is None:
#   print "NONE"
#   sp = str(20)
#------------------------------------------------
    # get data from the database
    records=get_data(option)

    # print the HTTP header
    printHTTPheader()

    if len(records) != 0:
        # convert the data into a table
        table=create_table(records)
    else:
        print "No data found"
        return

    # start printing the page

    print "<html>"
    # print the head section including the table
    # used by the javascript for the chart
    printHTMLHead("Temperature Logger", table)

    # print the page body
    print "<body>"
    print "<h1>Temperature Logger</h1>"
    print "<hr>"
    print_time_selector(option)
    print_setpoint_selector(sp)
    show_graph()
    show_stats(option,sp)
    print "</body>"
    print "</html>"

    sys.stdout.flush()


if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```